# bash script outputting to another file to be read by conky

Tags: bash

How can I make this

```
echo 'kindle' - `( du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/obkindle |awk '{ print $1; }' )`
```

output to another file to just give a name and a figure and a gb [2.0gb for example] which can then be read by conky please? So the final output will show something like this

```
kindle - 2.0gb
```

This is the full script of "baksize" called every 5 minutes (for testing only) from a cron job

```
 echo 'kindle' - ` du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/obkindle |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow 'kindle-rsync' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/Kindle |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow
 echo 'home' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/obnam-home |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow 'back4' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/obnam-back4 |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow
 echo 'blog' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/obblog |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow  'blogrs' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/blogback |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow
 echo 'galaxyrs' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/galaxy |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow 'back2a' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/ob-back2a |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow
 echo 'back2b' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/ob-back2b |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow 'back2c' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/ob-back2c |awk '{ print $1; }'`>~/bin/backshow
```

and this is "backshow"

```
 ob-home      204.83gb  music            325.08gb   
 ob-blog        23.92gb   rsync-blog       .70gb           
 2a               671.92gb  2b                   244.23gb          
 2c               28.01gb   2d                    469.98gb         
 ob-kindle     2.56gb    rsync-kindle     .97gb
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need `()` around the commands in backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is not 100% clear thus this solution covering few variants

```
#!/bin/bash

file=~/bin/backshow
if ! >$file; then
        echo "Error: Access issue while creating file";
        exit 1;
fi

function ComposeFile() { #arg1 friendly_name; arg2 dir
        size_kb=`(du -s $2 | awk '{print $1}') 2>/dev/null`;
        if [ -n "${size_kb}" ]; then
                #calculate into gb with 2 floting ponts controlled by scale
                gb=`echo "scale=2; $size_kb / 1024 / 1024" | bc -l`;
                #if you need wider columns change 25 into i.e. 35
                printf '%-25s %-25s\n' "$1" "${gb}gb" >> $file
        fi
}

ComposeFile temp /var/tmp
ComposeFile doesnt_exist /dummy
ComposeFile another_dir /opt
ComposeFile dell /opt/dell
ComposeFile blahblah /opt
ComposeFile ufffff /opt

#joins every second line
sed -i '$!N;s/\n/ /' $file
cat $file

exit 0;
```

new output:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./stackoverflow.sh
temp                 0gb                  another_dir          3.41gb
dell                 .30gb                blahblah             3.41gb
ufffff               3.41gb
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working well, but I fear that "backshow" will contain lots of output, with output everytime "stackoverflow.sh" runs. How do we get it so that "backshow" only contains the last output from "stackoverflow.sh" please?

Comment: Third line preempts this file '>$file'

Comment: How can I get the "one entry per line" output to two columns please? Its currently parsing 10 folders which would be easier to read as 2 columns.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, but its still in one column, instead of the hoped for 2

Comment: printf was set to 2 columns `printf '%-25s %-25s\n' "$1" "${gb}gb" >> $file` could you please provide me with an example of desired output?

Comment: `sed -i '$!N;s/\n/ /' $file` this will produce an output similar to yours. I hope this will allow you to accept this solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `> filename` to redirect to a file:

```
echo 'kindle' - `du -sh /media/boudiccas/back1/obkindle |awk '{ print $1; }'` > filename
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not working, so I've refined my question with further information, but "backshow" is only getting 2 instances of the output in one line, as I've shown.

Comment: if you want to send multiple commands to the same file, use `>>` to append to the file. `>` overwrites.